# How do I list all Docker containers which have been started by Testcontainers?

Tags: docker, testcontainers

I am running some integration tests which uses [Testcontainers](https://testcontainers.com/). However, I have a few other Docker containers running on my machine as well. How can I filter my `docker ps` listing to only include the containers launched by Testcontainers?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--filter` parameter in `docker ps`:

```
plundberg@delorean:~/git/hiboxcentre$ docker ps --filter label=org.testcontainers=true
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                         NAMES
a6b153041b9d   mariadb:10.1                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   0.0.0.0:32831->3306/tcp, :::32831->3306/tcp   data-and-schema-migration-db-1985304750
0c31721f4678   testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1   "/bin/ryuk"              9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   0.0.0.0:32830->8080/tcp, :::32830->8080/tcp   testcontainers-ryuk-2cf5c115-4da6-41d0-94a4-06ed84967b2e
```

The same parameter also works with `docker network ls`, btw:

```
plundberg@delorean:~/git/hiboxcentre$ docker network ls --filter label=org.testcontainers=true
NETWORK ID     NAME                                   DRIVER    SCOPE
dd013d6db7b9   0dd7c00a-19be-4650-a770-7819aa8ae4e8   bridge    local
```